# Is the given statement true?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, continuity

Does there exist a continous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R})= \mathbb{Z}$ (the set of integers)?

If yes then please provide with an example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, there isn't such a function. Hint: The intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.

Answer (score 3):

If $(X,T)$ is a connected topological space and $f$ a continous and surjective function between $(X,T)$ and $(Y,S)$, then $(Y,S)$ is connected.
There is no such function because $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not. The continous function would be surjective over $\mathbb{Z}$, making $\mathbb{Z}$ connected (in the usual topology restricted to $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I forgot to ad connected! Sorry!